# How can i setvalue in firebase with a string?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, setvalue

I want to make a mail's user database, when user create one account, it will automatically create one node in firebase. For example

```
public void onSuccess(Map<String, Object> result) {
                        String mail = edtMailSignUp.getText().toString();
                        Firebase rt = root.child(mail);
                        rt.setValue(mail);
}
```

When i ran it, it failed. How can i fix it?

Comment: What's does it mean I have a bug? Can you explain the bug?

Answer (score 0):

The method `setValue()` will overwrite the data at the specified location, including any child nodes.

You can use the `push()` method that generates a unique ID every time a new child is added to the specified Firebase reference.

```
Firebase rt = root.child(mail);
rt.push().setValue(mail);
```

If you would like to insert more data (as name, age....) you can use a Pojo to store the info:

```
public class User {
    private int age;
    private String email;
    private String name;

    //Use the empty constructor
    public User() {}

   // Getters and setters
   //.....
}
```

Then:

```
Firebase rt = root.child("users"); //Your users root
User myUser = new User();
myUser.setName(".....");
myUser.setAge(xx);
myUser.setEmail(".....");
rt.push().setValue(myUser);
```

Comment: but can i set infomation of specific mail like name, age or something else? i used push, but i dont know how to set infomation's mail

Answer (score 0):

I  make this

```
@Override
                    public void onSuccess(Map<String, Object> result) {
                        String mail = edtMailSignUp.getText().toString();
                        MailDatabase mDtb = new MailDatabase();
                        mDtb.setTime("1234");
                        mDtb.setContent("hongphat");
                        root.push().setValue(mDtb);
                    }
```

And this

```
public class MailDatabase {
private String time;
private String content;

public MailDatabase(){

}

public void setTime(String _time){
    time = _time;
}
public void setContent(String _content){
    content = _content;
}
}
```

But it got bug. Is this wrong?